# Divide Column by Sum of Data Subset in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like the following:

```
pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E'}, 'Count': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, 'Group': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'B'}})
```

which looks like this:

```
Change  Count   Group
0   A   1   A
1   B   2   A
2   C   3   A
3   D   4   B
4   E   5   B
```

I would like to group by the `Group` column, find the sum of all the counts in the `Count` column for that subset and then create a new column `Proportion` which is calculated as the values in the `Count` column for that subset divided by the sum of that subset.

The result should look result in this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Change': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E'}, 'Count': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, 'Group': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'B'}, 'Proportion': {0: 0.167, 1: 0.333, 2: 0.5, 3: 0.444, 4: 0.555}})
```

and look like this:

```
Change  Count   Group   Proportion
0   A   1   A   0.167
1   B   2   A   0.333
2   C   3   A   0.500
3   D   4   B   0.444
4   E   5   B   0.555
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `groupby` with `transform`

```
df['new'] = df['Count'].div(df.groupby('Group')['Count'].transform('sum'))
df
Out[176]: 
  Change  Count Group       new
0      A      1     A  0.166667
1      B      2     A  0.333333
2      C      3     A  0.500000
3      D      4     B  0.444444
4      E      5     B  0.555556
```

Answer (score 1):

I would follow these steps:

- Get group totals:

```
groups = df[['Group', 'Count']].groupby('Group').sum().reset_index()
```

- Merge df with groups so each row has the group total count:

```
df = pd.merge(df, groups, on='Group')
```

- Compute proportions:

```
df['Proportion'] = df['Count'] / df['sum']
```